# React Navigator not pushing to new component, reloads the same one

Tags: react-native

What is wrong with the code I have written below. From my understanding the Push method of the Navigator should load a new component which my navigator instance with render. However when I press the TouchableHighlight to load my second page I just get a transition and the same page loads, I'm also using Navigator over NavigatorIOS because I want to create an app for both Android and iOS.

```
    /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Navigator,
  TouchableHighlight
} = React;

var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

var SecondPage = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <View style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
                <Text>Second page</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
});

var HomePage = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <View 
                style={{ marginTop: 40 }}
                >
                <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress={() => {
                        alert('go to second page')

                        this.props.navigator.push({
                            title: 'second page',
                            component: SecondPage
                        })
                    }}
                >
                    <Text>Homepage here</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        )
    }
});

var NavigationTest = React.createClass({
    renderScene: function(route, nav) {
        console.log('renderScene');
        return (
            <HomePage
                navigator={nav}
            />
        );
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <Navigator
                ref='navigatorRef'
                sceneStyle={styles.container}
                initialRoute={{ 
                    name: "First Scene",
                }}
                renderScene={this.renderScene}
                navigationBar={
                    <View style={styles.navbar}>
                        <View>
                            <TouchableHighlight
                                style={{ padding:15, width:100 }}
                                underlayColor={'#ff6600'}
                            >
                                <Text>Back</Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                }
            />
        );
    }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    marginTop:75,
    padding:15
  },
  navbar: {
    backgroundColor:'red',
    position:'absolute',
    top:0,
    width:windowWidth,
    paddingTop:30,
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('NavigationTest', () => NavigationTest);
```

Answer (score 0):

It exactly reloads the same one.

See the [example](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator/NavigatorExample.js) here.

Comment: Thanks I had looked at the documentation, but kind of overlooked the renderScene method, looking back at it i've got my example working. So it seem like renderScene is used for rendering every scene after a push method is initialised, I initially thought it was just for the first scene.